# simple jquery append doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery

There's code (sorry if its too messy). I know it's stupid and stuff but i cant figure it out.

The deal is to add some content into that div with id movtip depending on if client is mobile or not (i got own class to deal with it so dont worry):

```
if ($deviceType !== telephone && $deviceType !== tablet) {

  echo '
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable" id="movtip"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (getCookie(\'hideTip\') != 1) {
    $(\'#movtip\').append(\'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-
hidden="true" onclick="hideTip();">&times;</button>blah blah\');
</script>';

} else {

    echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (getCookie(\'hideTip\') != 1) {
    $(\'#movtip\').append(\'<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"         onclick="hideTip();">&times;</button>
blah blah</div>\');
</script>'; 

}
```

Comment: Can you explain whats not working?

Comment: The code looks good, you could be having problems with your cookie "hideTip", perhaps getCookie('hideTip') is in fact returning 1?

Comment: you have code error. } is missed. You can use https://getfirebug.com/ for debug Javascript codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (sorry if its too messy)

This *is* your problem. At the very least there's a syntax error in your JavaScript but because of how you've formatted your code (and chosen to echo it rather than using block syntax in PHP) it's almost impossible to spot:

```
<?php if ($deviceType !== telephone && $deviceType !== tablet) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable" id="movtip"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (getCookie('hideTip') != 1) {
            $('#movtip').append('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" onclick="hideTip();">&times;</button>blah blah');
    </script>

<?php else: ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (getCookie('hideTip') != 1) {
                $('#movtip').append('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" onclick="hideTip();">&times;</button>blah blah</div>')
    </script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Notice that

```
if (getCookie('hideTip') != 1) {
```

Opens a block but there's no closing brace to close that block?

Neat code that's easy to understand is code which is likely to contain fewer bugs ;)